# Lightning Flow Builder - compare a date field to $Flow.CurrentDate

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm looking for a way to set a condition requirement that a specific date field will be equal to today's date, or yesterday's.
How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: I can just start the flow without an object and then add "Net Get Record" step. there, I have the ability to compare a date variable to a global flow variable, but I still didn't figure out how to compare to yesterday - if I do ({!$Flow.CurrentDate}-1) I get "We don't recognize that value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new formula resource of type `Date` and name it `yesterday` (or whatever) and put that code in there.

`{!$Flow.CurrentDate} - 1`

***Edit:*** I am not sure if you are doing something differently but here is a screenshot of a `Get Records` flow element filtering based on a formula value:

[image: get records, filter on formula value]

And to be perfectly clear, here is a screenshot of that formula definition:

[image: date formula definition: yesterday]

Comment: Unfortunately, on "Choose Object and Filter Conditions" step you can't compare a field to a formula...

Comment: I added screenshots to my answer. This a standard autorun flow and it runs with no errors as  well. I am not sure what you are doing differently that is giving you issues...

Comment: Thank you Abraham!

Comment: Ah, that worked! Glad to hear! Thanks for following up... Best of luck!